# Terminating the code if javascript is not found

Tags: javascript, noscript

Im trying to show a message if there is no javascript enabled in browser using  and then i want not to further proceed to load the page. Im using php so i did

```
<?php exit;?>
```

in the noscipt but though the browser has javascript enabled the php code exit works...
the code i used is like this:

```
<noscript>
        <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px; color:#f00; margin-bottom:10px;text-decoration: blink;">
            <h1>
                Please enable javascript<br style="margin-bottom: 5px;"/>
                <h3>Else the system will not work correctly.</h3>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <div class="title" style="font:bold 18px arial">Enabling Javascript</div>
            For: <strong>FireFox</strong>
            Go To:<strong>Options > Content</strong><br/> and Check the Enable Javascript.
            <br/>OR<br/>
            Refer this link to enable javascript according to your browser<br/>
            <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/">http://www.enable-javascript.com/</a>
            <?php exit;?>
        </div>
    </noscript>
```

what should i do not to proceed further if javascript is not enabled and should proceed if js is enabled...

Comment: PHP runs on server side, while `<noscript>` is a client-side element. PHP generates content (whatever content) and send them to client **and then** browsers render them. PHP has no idea how the content is/should be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

[noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp) blocks are executed when javascript is disabled, and are used to display alternative content.

```
<noscript>
    <b>You don't have javascript enabled.</b>
</noscript>
```

or you can redirect user to another page if javascript is disabled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <noscript>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; /?javascript=no">
        </noscript>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
</html>
```

In your php code you can check

```
if(isset($_GET['javascript']) && $_GET['javascript'] == 'no')
{
    exit;
}
```

Comment: the solution for my problem would be the if statement but it didn't work well...there was no response for that

Answer (score 0):

Use `<noscript>` tag -

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Also you can try this

```
if(isset($_GET['nojs']) && !isset($_SESSION['no_script']))
{
    $_SESSION['no_script'] = true; //Or cookie
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a redirect, so you send the users to a page with  a message like Sorry you can't visit the site if JAVASCRIPT is Disabled.

```
 <noscript>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/nojsmessage.php" />
  </noscript>
```